# Java - regex match in String vs. readline in file

Tags: java, regex, file, bufferedreader, readline

I don't understand this strange behaviour of regex match in Java. I'm working in Eclipse...

I have a .txt file encoded in UTF-8, where are blocks of text lines divided by these identifiers:

```
[a]
.
.
.
[b]
.
.
[c]
```

and so on...

My program is reading this file with this `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) { System.out.println("File not found!"); e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(0); }
```

---

**This should find the first identifier:**

```
String line = "";
while (!line.matches("^\\[.\\]$")) { line = reader.readLine(); }
```

**But it is instantly skipped!**

---

**But when I try to test the regex "manually", it works:**

```
String line = "[a]";
if (line.matches("^\\[.\\]$")) { System.out.println("Regex matches"); }
```

---

It is possible that it is some trivial problem, but I get totally stuck at this point!
Thanks in advance for reply!

EDIT:

**Well, I changed the encoding of text file to "ANSI" and it just started to work fine - OH MY GOD - why?! So there must be problem with the `reader` - I will try to find it out as soon as possible and edit my question.**

So when the encoding of text file is "UTF-8", the regex doesn't match the first line of text file, where is "[a]" and matches the next identifier few lines below. **What is wrong?**

EDIT 2:

**LOL I can't trust the Windows Notepad anymore - I had saved that file in it...and a few moments ago I saved that file using PSPad editor and now it works fine!**

Comment: There was a comment (already deleted), where somebody advised me to use this regex match: `line.matches("^\\[.\\][\n\r]")`
because of newline characters on each line.
But that doesn't help since `readline()` strips the newline character...

Comment: Notepad is notorious for adding a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when you save something as UTF-8, and Java is notorious for treating the BOM as a regular character, even if you specify UTF-8 as the encoding.  They're both wrong, but your best bet is, as you said, to quit using Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `FileInputStream` does **not** have a constructor with parameters **file** and **character set** ([JavaDoc JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)). Maybe you got a typo in your code?

```
new FileInputStream("file.txt", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

So is this a different implementation of `FileInputStream`?

Second I tried this little test with a bracket modification:

```
    BufferedReader reader;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              new FileInputStream("target/classes/test.txt"), 
              Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String line = "";
    while (!line.matches("^\\[.\\]$")) { line = reader.readLine(); }

    System.out.println(line);
```

And it just worked and printed:

```
[a]
```

Comment: "_First of all FileInputStream does not have a constructor with parameters file and character set_" ... but you used that and it works, so it is ok? I have seen that on some tutorial page... **Well, I changed the encoding of text file to "ANSI" and it just started to work fine - OH MY GOD - why?! So there must be problem with the `reader` - I will try to find it out as soon as possible and edit my question.**

Comment: I didnt use it. I modified the brackets. The character set goes to the InputStreamReader. Maybe your file is not utf8 encoded?

Comment: LOL I can't trust the Windows Notepad anymore - I had saved that file in it...and a few moments ago I saved that file using PSPad editor and now it works fine! But thanks for reply anyway :)